# hidding the runfile() command in Spyder

Tags: python-3.x, ipython, spyder

Is there a way to 'hide' the runfile() command so that it doesn't get displayed on the IPython console?  It can get really annoying when the file has a long path since it displays the path twice:

```
runfile('C:/Users/One/Desktop/Training/Week1/Files/file1.py',wdir='C:/Users/One/Desktop/Training/Week1/Files/file1.py')
```

Comment: Open two ipython consoles, one for running the files, and one for using as an ipython console (consoles > open new ipython console).

Answer (score 3):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is not possible in our current stable version (Spyder **4**), sorry.

Comment: Hi Carlos, is there a way to avoid runfile now?

Comment: No, it's not, sorry. I updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you, I hate having a cluttered IPython console .

I found a way while I was trying to find a solution to clear the  old text in the console when starting a script:

Define an anonymous function (reference: https://python-forum.io/Thread-Difference-between-os-system-clear-and-os-system-cls) at the beginning of your script to clear the console from text

```
cls = lambda: print("\033[2J\033[;H", end='')

cls()
```

The annoying `runfile (...)`  text section will disappear :)

Answer (score 2):

This is how I made Alexis' idea work reliably for me. My screen got updated by my code before cls() finished executing, consequently it was blanked over.

```
from time import sleep

def cls():
    print("\033[2J\033[;H", end='')
    sleep(0.1)

cls()
```