# How to select what IPython console showes in Spyder?

Tags: python, console, ipython, spyder

I want to reduce amount of information that I get in console when I run code.

What I get is:

```
C:\Users\hrdinhal\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py:252: DataConversionWarning: A column-vector y was passed when a 1d array was expected. Please change the shape of y to (n_samples, ), for example using ravel().
  y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
Thresh=0.054, n=590, Accuracy: 57.14%
Thresh=0.054, n=590, Accuracy: 59.52%
```

What I want to get is:

```
Thresh=0.054, n=590, Accuracy: 57.14%
Thresh=0.054, n=590, Accuracy: 59.52%
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [hidding the runfile() command in Spyder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50972253/hidding-the-runfile-command-in-spyder)

Comment: I've done a decent scan of Spyder 4 and I can't see that they did end up implementing it as an option